# Regex for matching number ranges with specific units

Tags: python, regex

I need help to complete a regex pattern. I need a pattern to match a range of numbers including unit.

Examples:

- The car drives **50,5 - 80 km/10min** on the road.
- The car drives **50,5 - 80 km / 10min** on the road.
- The car drives **40,5-80 km/h** on the road.
- The car drives **30-50 km/h** on the road.
- The car drives **40 - 60.8 km/ h** on the road.
- The car drives **40.90-60,8 km/h** on the road.

I need to match the entire ranges. Good would also be (?:km/10min|km / 10min|km/h|km/ h) to simplify this part so that this does not have to be listed multiple times. So also here the blanks taken into account.

```
([,.\d]+)\s*(?:km/10min|km / 10min|km/h|km/ h)
```

https://regex101.com/r/Ey792V/1

Currently, unfortunately, only the first number is matched. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make the pattern a bit more specific and optionally match whitespace chars instead of hard coding all the possible spaces variations

```
\b\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?(?:\s*-\s*\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?)?\s*km\s*/\s*(?:h|10min)\b
```

**Explanation**

- `\b` A word boundary
- `\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?` Match 1+ digits with an optional decimal part
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\s*-\s*` Match `-` between optional whitespace chars
  - `\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?` Match 1+ digits with an optional decimal part
- `)?` Close the non capture group and make it optional
- `\s*km\s*/\s*` Match `km/` surrounded with optional whitespace chars to match different variations
- `(?:h|10min)` Match either `h` or `10min` (Or use `\d+min` to match 1+ digits)
- `\b` A word boundary

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3PCozI/1).

Comment: Thanks for the quick help and the good explanation! I think the first answer was a little closer to what I need, since other units can also be added. e.g. mph, kg, cm/s. The second regex (after edit) always implies a link to "km". So the second one is shorter but the first pattern is easier for me to add more units with my knowledge.

Comment: @yllwpr The pattern can be updated by putting the units in an alternation like `\b\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?(?:\s*-\s*\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?)?\s*(?:km\s*/\s*(?:h|10min)|mph)\b` see https://regex101.com/r/QJdQRn/1

Comment: I rather mean a list where I can add more units and they are also recognized including spaces. All possibilities should be covered. ```(?:km/10min|km / 10min|km/h|km/ h|cm/s|cm/ s|cm / s)```. The reference to km was only an example.

Comment: @yllwpr You can add `\s*` to all the places where there can be 0 or more whitespace characters https://regex101.com/r/RzFJ51/1

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not entirely clear as you framed it in terms of examples. To be precise you need to state the question in words, then use the examples for illustration. To take one example, the question does not make clear whether

```
"The car drives 40,5- 80 km /h on the road."
```

is to be matched.

Expressing a question in words is not always easy but it is a skill that you need to acquire in order write clear code specifications. A by-product is that it makes the code easier to write, as that amounts to merely translating the words into code.

Let's give it a try.

Match a string comprised by six successive substrings:

1. One or more digits that are not preceded by a comma or period, optionally followed by a comma, hyphen or period, which, if present, is followed by one or more digits.
2. A hyphen, optionally preceded and/or followed by a space.
3. One or more digits, optionally followed by a comma or period, the comma or period, if present, being followed by one or more digits.
4. The literal " km".
5. A forward slash, optionally preceded and/or followed by a space.
6. The literal "h" or one or more digits followed by "min", followed by a word boundary.

I cannot be sure that this is what you want but you should be able to easily modify these requirements as necessary.

Now let's translate these requirements into a regular expression.

**1. One or more digits that are not preceded by a comma or period, optionally followed by a comma, hyphen or period, which, if present, is followed by one or more digits.**

```
(?<![,.])\d+(?:[,.-]\d+)?
```

`(?<![,.])` is a negative *lookbehind*. It is needed to avoid matching, for example, the indicated part of the following string.

```
"The car drives 1,500.5 - 80 km/10min on the road."
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

**2. A hyphen, optionally preceded and/or followed by a space.**

```
 ?- ?
```

(The first question mark is preceded by a space.)

**3. One or more digits, optionally followed by a comma or period, the comma or period, if present, being followed by one or more digits.**

```
\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?
```

**4. The literal " km".**

```
km
```

**5. A forward slash, optionally preceded and/or followed by a space.**

```
 ?\/ ?
```

(The first question mark is preceded by a space.)

**6. The literal "h" or one or more digits followed by "min", followed by a word boundary.**

```
(?:h|\d+min)\b
```

---

Now we can simply join these pieces to form the regular expression.

```
\d+(?:[,.-]\d+)? ?- ?\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?km ?\/ ?(?:h|\d+min)\b
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/s091IA/1)

Comment: Now that's an explanation :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
\d.+(?:h\b|min\b|s\b)
```

Would also work. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5AbBWQ/1)